# Asynchronous message on internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, asynchronous, message

I'm trying to fix a problem. Basically I need to show a "loading message" on a long running Javascript code, and hide it when this code ends, so something like:

showMessage();

executeMyCode();

hideMessage();

However, I'm having problems while getting this working on Internet Explorer,right now it appears like the page is frozen until all the script code finishes, and this can be annoying to the users. I have tried an approach using the setTimeout(), but this is not working, have any of u got this solved? I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function showMessage(){
    /* show message */;
    window.delay=setTimeout(executeMyCode,100); // Give some time to browser to render message
    return;
}

function executeMyCode(){
    clearTimeout(window.delay);
    /* execute long running code */
    /* hide message */
    return;
}
```

Though browser will still be frozen while executing the long code, user can now see the message.